# How do i place a Fragment inside a custom Dialog with Custom View?

Tags: android

Hello i use my own Dialog class with custom layout
for everything else works fine
i have worked with listviews gridviews and so on
but when i try to put a fragment inside the dialog View programmatically then it crashes
with

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0167 (com.myapp.app:id/frame1) for fragment CaldroidFragment{448be1b8 #0 id=0x7f0d0167}
```

i Want to use https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid  for calendar.

When i put it like this in the layout

```
<fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment"
            />
```

it works but i can't get it programmatically 
with findbytag or findbyid
then again if i try to put it programmatically in a FrameLayout for instance, then it crashes with the above IllegalArgumentException.

From what i think, the Activity Instance Support Fragment Manager, only knows that fragments that are in its own view hierarchy and ignores the Dialog's View hieararchy but how can i get this fragment programmatically in order to interact with it?

```
public class DialogFiltersDates {
Dialog dialog;

RelativeLayout rl;
private TextView tv_title;
private TextView tv_messge;
private TextView left_button;
private TextView right_button;
    Act_filters father;
    private FrameLayout fr_Dates;
    private FrameLayout fr1;

    /*******
     * Constructor
     * @param ctx
     */
public DialogFiltersDates(Context ctx){
    father = (Act_filters)ctx;
    if (dialog==null){
        dialog = new Dialog(ctx, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
         dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_filters_date);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
}

    /*****
     * Showers
     * @param context
     * @param title
     * @param message

     */
public void show_notice(final Context context, String title, String message, final Runnable task_for_left,final Runnable task_for_right) {
        work_on_dialog_init(context, title, message, task_for_left, task_for_right);
    }


    /*******
     * Initializer
     * @param context
     * @param title
     * @param message
     * @param task_for_left

     */
private void work_on_dialog_init(final Context context, String title, String message, final Runnable task_for_left, final Runnable task_for_right){


    if (dialog!=null) {
        Log.i("DialogNotices", "dialog was already opened-->"+dialog.getContext().getClass().toString());
        Log.i("DialogNotices","trying to open from-->"+context.getClass().toString());
    }
    //if is null or not from this activity
    if (dialog==null || !dialog.getContext().getClass().toString().equals(context.getClass().toString())){
        dialog=null;
        dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_filters_date);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                dialog=null;
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
     left_button = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.left_btn);
     right_button = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.right_btn);

//   rl = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rlmain);
//  this.tv_title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message_title);
//  this.tv_messge = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
     fr1 = (FrameLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.frame1);
//  right_button.setText("Ok");
//
    left_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (task_for_left != null) {
                task_for_left.run();
            }
        }
    });

    right_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (task_for_right != null) {
                task_for_right.run();
            }

        }
    });
    if ( !( (Activity) (context) ).isFinishing() ){
        dialog.show();
    }
    setupCalendar();
}

    private void setupCalendar() {
        CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment = new CaldroidFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        args.putInt(CaldroidFragment.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = father.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //List<Fragment> asda = father.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
        t.replace(R.id.frame1, caldroidFragment);
        t.commit();
        CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment2 = (CaldroidFragment) father. getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentByTag("CaldroidFragment");
                //findFragmentById(R.id.frag_date2);

        if (caldroidFragment!=null) {
            caldroidFragment.setArguments(args);
        }


    }

    public void dismiss(){
        this.dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it like this.

i remove all fragments from the fragment manager
every time i instatiate the dialog 
because there was also an instance if the fragment when it inflated the layout.

```
public void remove_all_frags(){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = father.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    List<Fragment> all_frags = father.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (all_frags!=null && all_frags.size()>0){
        for (Fragment a_frag:all_frags) {
            if (a_frag!=null){
                Log.i("Dialog Dates","removing-- "+a_frag.getTag()+ " - class-- " + a_frag.getContext().getClass().toString());
                t.remove(a_frag);
            }
        }
        t.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i put it like this in the layout

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment"
/>
```

> it works but i can't get it programmatically with findbytag or
>   findbyid then again if i try to put it programmatically in a
>   FrameLayout for instance, then it crashes with the above method.

Have you given the fragment a unique id for the layout? Without it, it will be impossible to find the view.

```
android:id=@+id/my_id
```

Comment: Yes ofCourse as you can see i have   CaldroidFragment caldroidFragment2 = (CaldroidFragment) father. getSupportFragmentManager().
            findFragmentByTag("CaldroidFragment");
                //findFragmentById(R.id.frag_date2);
and i have both tried 
android:id=@+id/my_id and android:tag="my_tag" and still crashes

Comment: and there is the crash:    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #54: Duplicate id 0x7f0d0167, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0d015b with another fragment for com.roomorama.caldroid.CaldroidFragment